# ''Creative Loading Effects'' demo onload when page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onload, preloader

I'm finding a preloader for my web and i found this demo [Creative Loading Effects](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/09/18/creative-loading-effects/), the "3D Bar Bottom" effects is very exciting.

But there only one problem that it's only loading when we press the button, it's not onload when the page load like i want. (i want it's onload like [this](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) but this don't have the "3D Bar Bottom" effects).

So:

How to make these demo onload as pageloading?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you're better off trying to make something yourself than just copying and pasting tutorials/components. Look into Ajax navigation and preloading of resources.

Comment: Thanks, i'm just starting learn js-css so i don't know much, just want to learn from SO and free components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you can do it like this;

**jQuery;**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".la-anim-1").trigger('click');
});
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/8vnQF/)

its a Guerrilla Creativity! :)

Comment: Seam like it's not real preloader like [here](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) right? Not what i need but anyway, Thanks.